# как найти элементы массива Numpy, для которых задана сумма

Tags: python, numpy

Есть простая задача определить индексы элементов массива Numpy, сумма которых меньше определённого числа.
Причем элементы должны суммироваться от наибольшего до наименьшего, пока не получится число близкое к заданной сумме. Как сделать это без циклов с помощью Numpy? Спасибо!

```
import numpy as np
massiv = np.random.sample(10)
print('исходный массив ', massiv)
summa_zadano = 2.0
print('заданная сумма: ', summa_zadano)
massiv_sort = np.sort(massiv)
massiv_obratn_sort = massiv_sort[::-1]
indeksi_massiva_sort = np.argsort(massiv)[::-1]
massiv_obratn_sort = np.take_along_axis(massiv, indeksi_massiva_sort, axis=0)
for i in range(len(massiv)):
    summa = np.sum(massiv_obratn_sort[0:i+1])
    if summa >= summa_zadano:
        print(massiv_obratn_sort[0:i])
        print(np.sum(massiv_obratn_sort[0:i]))
        print(indeksi_massiva_sort[0:i])
        break
```

Comment: очень советую вам прочесть [pep8 на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) или [официальный pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (слёзно вас прошу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сортированного массива посчитать кумулятивные суммы (cumsum) и бинарным поиском найти нужную.

Comment: здесь даже не содержится код...

Comment: вам стоит дополнить ответ

Comment: @Александр Очевидно, что человек код писать умеет, достаточно подсказать направление.

Comment: хм, переменные называть он точно не умеет. :)
а вам стоит хоть ссылки отставить на документацию функций

Comment: @Александр, вы можете написать собственный вариант ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
massiv = np.random.sample(10)
print('исходный массив: ', massiv)
summa = 2.0
indeksi_1 = np.argsort(massiv)[::-1]
massiv_2 = np.take_along_axis(massiv, indeksi_1, axis=0)
s = np.cumsum(massiv_2)
indeksi_2 = np.where(s < summa)[0]
indeksi_1[indeksi_2]
```